# updating GridView is vewry slow

Tags: android, gridview

I have TableLayout with 6-16 GridView, each GridView has 6 - 10 visible elements with timer. Timer updated every seconds. It works very slow, if I doing somthing it's handled 1-2 seconds. For update I used invalidateViews(), notifydatasetchanged(). It will be faster if I only update TextView in View without invalidateViews()? Who knows another way to update GridView?

Here the code of updaiting:

```
private void updateAllGridView() {
    if(isTimeUpdateble) {
        for (int i = 0; i < mServisAreaList.size(); i++) {
            ((GridView)contentView.findViewWithTag(mServisAreaList.get(i).servisAreaName)).invalidateViews();       
        }           
    }   
}
```

Comment: update the underlying data that populated griview and call `notifyDataSetChanged` on your adapter

Comment: don't work for me, with notifyDataSetChanged() I have the same problem.

Comment: the problem is your for loop. it will work. update the data that populates listview. and call `notifyDataSetChanged` on your adapter once to refresh gridview. You have not posted how you populate gridview

Comment: also "I have TableLayout with 6-16 GridView, each GridView has 6 - 10". What are you trying to achieve with so many gridviews in a single layout?

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but how do I update all GridView at every second?

Comment: first i would rethink and redesign. Is there a real need for having so many gridviews. It certainly not a good design

Comment: requirement of customer(

Comment: look like this http://s020.radikal.ru/i718/1311/40/bf677d421e19.jpg